# PHP Classes Functions Undefined Index

Tags: php, function, class, undefined

I have this script. In the main php file I create a new takeover class, I addideastakeover() (everything words until now) but when I call the function takeover() it tells me  that ideastakeover is an undefined variable. Can someone help?

Class:

```
    class takeover {
    /**
     * @AttributeType int
     */
    private $idtakeover;
    /**
     * @AssociationType root
     * @AssociationMultiplicity 1
     */
    public $_unnamed_root_;

    public $ideiastakeover=array();

    public function __construct($idtakeover){
        $this->idtakeover = $idtakeover;
    }
    /**
     * @access public
     */
    public function getidcompraroot() {
        // Not yet implemented
    }

    public function addideiastakeover($idtakeover, $idideia) {
        $this->idtakeover = $idtakeover;
        $this->idideia = $idideia;
        array_push($this->ideiastakeover,$idideia);
        //print join(" ",$this->ideiastakeover);
    }

        /**
     * @access public
     */
    public function takeover() {
        echo $ideiastakeover[1];
    }
}
```

How I call it on the main script:

```
$takeover = new takeover(1);

    for ($i=0; $i<$conta; $i++ ){
        $takeover->addideiastakeover(1,$idsideias[$i]);
    }

    $takeover->takeover(); //PROBLEM ON THIS LINE
```

Can someone help? Thank you :)

Comment: Please start using camel case. This is just bloody awful to read. `$idtakeover` becomes `$idTakeOver` etc.

Comment: You say that `ideastakeover` is undefined, yet you're calling a similar word in here `echo $ideiastakeover` --- the word `ideas` in your error, seems to be mispelled often with `ideias` so I'm not quite sure how to take your code. This may very well fall into the `C.O.W.` code category, so I'm not touching this one.

Comment: I am still in university trying to learn a bit, I'll keep your advices in mind next time, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `takeover()` to:

```
public function takeover() {
    echo $this->ideiastakeover[1];
}
```

Comment: of couuurse haha! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You must use $this inside class:

```
echo $this->ideiastakeover[1];
```